# Change a dataframe column type from integer to a factor

Tags: python, r, dataframe, rpy2

My code in R has the following trivial assignment:

```
 df$a<-factor(df$a,levels=c("3","2","1"))
```

(the order of levels is important in plotting, so this probably must be done by an assignment like this)

How could I achieve the same result using `rpy2`? Let's say I have a DataFrame constructed like this:

```
from rpy2 import robjects

d = {'a': robjects.IntVector((1,2,3)), 'b': robjects.IntVector((4,5,6))}
dataf = robjects.DataFrame(d)
```

Now I would like to change the type of column `'a'` and set the order of levels in it, like I have done in R. Is it possible using rpy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix the levels in an R `factor`:

```
>>> from rpy2.robjects.vectors import FactorVector, IntVector
>>> v = FactorVector((1,2,3), levels=IntVector((3,2,1)))
>>> print(v)
[1] 1 2 3
Levels: 3 2 1
```

Changing a column in a DataFrame can be done with:

```
>>> dataf[dataf.index('a')] = v
```

Note: In R you are happily giving numerical values (integers) while specifying levels as strings. R does let you do so silently, but be aware that the internal representation of R "factor" vector is integer, and that mix might lead to unpleasant surprises.